# How to paste a raster image into Illustrator with pixels positioned 1:1

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixel, raster, pixel-grid, copy-and-paste

I have copied and pasted a raster image to Illustrator and this is what I get:

[image]

The pixels of the image obviously disagree with pixels of the grid, they're smaller and shifted.

Is it possible to paste an image where the pixels line up at exactly 1:1?

Comment: Set the raster image to 72ppi (resampling disabled) and save it, and the pixels will match. When importing into Illustrator make sure Align Art to Pixel Grid is switched on.

Comment: I am pasting grabbed screenshot without any `ppi` processing. No chance to proceed without intermediate file?

Comment: Do you have system scaling enabled on your computer? If so that might explain it. Try switching it off.

Comment: Just checked this again. If on Windows and you take a screenshot, the default is 96ppi You need to open the file in Photoshop or similar, change the ppi to 72 (without resampling). Save the file, then import into Illustrator.

Comment: I've added an answer now. I just checked this and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take your screenshot. Note in Windows screenshots are 96ppi by default
2. Open the screenshot in Photoshop, do *Image > Image Size*. Set PPI to 72, disable the Resample option.  If the image is already 72ppi you can skip the Photoshop steps.
3. Save the image as PNG
4. Open Illustrator, create a new document, choosing one of the Web presets. This will ensure Align Art to Pixel Grid is switched on by default
5. Import the image into Illustrator
6. Switch on the pixel preview, and zoom in to check the pixel grid